# jsf2 template component with parameter

Tags: jsf-2

I have a jsf template page. In this template i would like to use component with parameter. Actually i would like to iterate over collection. This collection should be determined by parameters from particular page. Parameter name is selectedMenu. How can i use this in my bean?

```
<div id="notes">
                    selectedMenu: #{selectedMenu}
                    <h:form>
                        <h:inputHidden value="#{notatkaController.searchForm.kategoria}">
                            <f:param value="#{selectedMenu}" />
                        </h:inputHidden>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{notatkaController.items}" var="item" varStatus="iter">
                            <f:param value="#{selectedMenu}" />
                            <p class="q-title"><strong><h:outputText value="#{item.ntaData}" /></strong></p>
                            <p class="answer"><h:outputText value="#{item.ntaDane}" escape="false" /></p>                                    
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <span>Moje notatki</span>
                        <textarea>Tu wpisz treść swojej notatki</textarea>
                        <span>[+] dodaj notatkę</span>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
```

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "notatkaController")
@ViewScoped
public class NotatkaController extends AbstractController<Notatka> implements Serializable {

@EJB
private pl.alfaprojekt.model.session.NotatkaFacade ejbFacade;
 private NotatkaSearchForm searchForm;

public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null)
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    return items;
}

public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        if (paginationSize == null)
            paginationSize = 10;
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(paginationSize) {

            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getFacade().countByParam(getSearchForm());
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                if (rapId == null)
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRangeByParam(getSearchForm(), new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                else {
                    Long uzyId = SessionUtil.getUser().getUzyId();
                    return new ListDataModel(convertToRaportWierszList(getFacade().findRangeByParam(getSearchForm(), new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}), uzyId));
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question but the question I answer is this:

I want to dynamically display something. I want to tell it what to display when the page gets accessed.

**View:**

You could then use the following:

```
<f:event listener="#{myBean.myMethod}" type="preRenderView" />
```

**Bean:**

```
public void myMethod(ComponentSystemEvent event){
//your logic here
}
```

**With parameter:**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{myBean.myMethod}" type="preRenderView" id="fevent"/>
    <f:attribute name="myParam" value="#{mySecondBean.param)" />
</f:metadata>
```

And

```
public void myMethod(ComponentSystemEvent event){
String id = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myParam");
}
```